# Eigenvalues of $M^{\top} D M$ with $M$ skew-symmetric and $D$ positive diagonal.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

I was wondering whether there was a way to bound the smallest eigenvalue of $M^{\top} D M$ when $M$ is skew-symmetric and $D$ is a positive diagonal matrix.

In particular, I was hoping that $M^{\top} D M$ would be positive definite, but it seems that this might only be the case if $M$ is full rank (since $D$ is not just a positive multiple of the diagonal).

Comment: The quadratic form associated to $M^\top D M$ takes only non-negative values, since the quadratic form associated to $D$ does.

Comment: Good point, Ben. It seemed too easy as I wrote it. Probably needed more coffee. I'll delete and re-post just the first sentence.

Comment: If $$ is skew-symmetric, then $^=−$, but $\det(^)=\det()$. In odd dimensions, that means that $$ necessarily has determinant zero, so it definitely won't be full-rank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $D$ is positive diagonal (i.e. diagonal with strictly positive diagonal entries), then for any (real) matrix $M$, $M^TDM$ will be positive semidefinite with rank equal to that of $M$. If $M$ has linearly independent columns, this means that $M^TDM$ will be positive definite.

To see that it $M^TDM$ is positive semidefinite, it suffices to note that for any vector $x$,
$$
x^T(M^TDM)x = (Mx)^TD(Mx) \geq 0.
$$
To see that the rank is the same as that of $M$, note that
$$
\operatorname{rank}(M^TDM) = \operatorname{rank}([D^{1/2}M]^T[D^{1/2}M]) = \operatorname{rank}(D^{1/2}M) = \operatorname{rank}(M).
$$
For your particular case, we can also get a bound on the smallest eigenvalue when the size of $M$ is even. Suppose that $M$ and $D$ are square even size. The smallest singular value of $M$ is the smallest absolute value among the eigenvalues of $M$, and the smallest singular value of $D$ is simply the smallest value on the diagonal. We have
$$
\sigma_{\min}(M^TDM) \geq \sigma_{\min}(M^T)\sigma_{\min}(D)\sigma_\min(M) = \sigma_\min(M)^2 \sigma_\min(D).
$$
On the other hand, $M^TDM$ is positive semidefinite, which means that its singular values are equal to its eigenvalues.